# PostgreSQL - Select tables where specific column is not present

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have a schema with about 3000 tables in a PostgreSQL DB, all having one row with the following columns:

`id`, `area`, `use`, `geom`, `site_id`

However, I just discovered that there's at least one table that misses the column `site_id`. I'm wondering if there are more of those.. How can I query for tables NOT having the column `site_id`?

My following idea doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'schema_A' AND column_name NOT LIKE 'site_id'
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be counting how many times `side_id` appears in that table's column listing.  If the sum is zero, the table has no `site_id`:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'schema_A'
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN column_name LIKE 'site_id' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

I'm also not sure if it was intentional or not, but `LIKE 'site_id'` will have the same effect as `= 'site_id'`.  If you meant to check if it contains `site_id`, `LIKE '%site_id%'` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I guess it was meant to compare exactly the column name with the literal `site_id` ...

Comment: @andrasz: No the HAVING clause filters, you get the table names as per the SELECT list. Just try it out - I did ;-) (comment of OP has disapeared)

Comment: @Dilettant: Yes, you were right: I was just looking for 'site_id' and yes it works. All my described (and now deleted) doubts vanished after having tried the code ;)
  Thanks Mr. Llama!

Comment: As of Postgres 9.4, you can replace the `SUM(CASE ...)` expression with `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE column_name LIKE 'site_id')`